# Measurability w.r.t. the $\sigma$-field induced on the range

Tags: measure-theory

**I asked here the wrong question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381671/measurability-w-r-t-the-sigma-field-induced-on-the-range-ii) for the correct one.**

Let there be given two measurable spaces $\left(S,\mathcal{S}\right)$ and $\left(T,\mathcal{T}\right)$ and suppose $f$ is a mapping from $S$ into $T$ (not necessarily measurable). According to Kallenberg ([KAL] Lemma 1.3(ii)), the set

$$
\mathcal{T}':=\left\{B\subseteq T;\space f^{-1} B\in\mathcal{S}\right\}
$$

is a $\sigma$-field in $T$.

Suppose $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$/$\mathcal{T}$-measurable. In general it need not be the case that $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$/$\mathcal{T}'$-measurable, but suppose $\left(T,\mathcal{T}\right)$ is a Borel space, i.e. there exists a measurable bijection $f:T\rightarrow U$, where $U$ is a Borel subset of $\left[0,1\right]$ and such that $f^{-1}$ is also measurable ([KAL] remark preceding Theorem A1.2). Is it the case that $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$/$\mathcal{T}'$-measurable?

### Background

The reason why i'm interested in this question is this. In the realm of statistics, some sources define a *statistic* as the $\sigma$-field $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}'\right)$ induced by a function $f:S\rightarrow T$ ([BAH] p. 429; consider also p. 430, where he defines a statistic to be sufficient iff the subfield $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}'\right)$ is sufficient.) In practice $T$ is a Borel space, usually a subset of $\mathfrak{B}^n$. It is usually easy to verify in these cases that $f$ is Borel measurable. Is this enough to ascertain that $f^{-1}\left(\mathfrak{B}\right)$ is a statistic?

### References

1. [BAH] Bahadur, R. R. Sufficiency and Statistical Decision Functions. Ann. Math. Statist. Volume 25, Number 3 (1954), 423-462
2. [KAL] Kallenberg, Olav. Foundations of Modern Probability. 2nd Edition. Springer. 2001.

Comment: There is no need to use html formatting here. The trouble you had with the link seems to be related to this (I couldn't get it to work either). An overview over the basics of markdown is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and a complete reference is [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Comment: @Martin: OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does not matter if $f$ is measurable with respect to any other $\sigma$-field.

$\mathcal{T^{'}}$ is THE $\sigma$-field induced by $f$, and trivially $f$ is measurable with respect to it, i.e., $f$ is $\mathcal{S}/\mathcal{T}^{'}$-measurable.

Comment: Right. Of course. Thanks.