# Measurability w.r.t. the $\sigma$-field induced on the range II

Tags: measure-theory

I'm sorry, but i asked the wrong question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381645/measurability-w-r-t-the-sigma-field-induced-on-the-range). What i meant to ask was whether $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}\right)=f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}'\right)$ in case $\left(T,\mathcal{T}\right)$ is a Borel space.

Comment: Isn't $f^{-1}(\mathcal{T}')\subseteq\mathcal{S}$ by definition, while $f^{-1}(\mathcal{T})$ can be much larger if $f$ isn't assumed to be measureable?

Comment: @StefanHansen: It is assumed that $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$/$\mathcal{T}$-measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(S,\mathcal{S})=\big([0,1],2^{[0,1]}\big)$, $(T,\mathcal{T})=\big([0,1],\mathcal{B}\big)$ with $\mathcal{B}$  the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $f=1_{[0,1]}$ be the identity on $[0,1]$. Then $$f^{-1}\big(\mathcal{T}'\big)=\mathcal{T}'=2^{[0,1]}\supsetneq\mathcal{B}=f^{-1}\big(\mathcal{T}\big).$$ Clearly, $(T,\mathcal{T})$ is a Borel space and $f$ measurable.

So the answer is no.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: @EvanAad You are welcome!